# PVS Health Check script

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, citrix

I'm getting an error when I run this script. I'm trying to debug it but I'm not really sure why I'm getting the error.

```
$currentDir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$logfile = Join-Path $currentDir ("PVSHealthCheck.log")
$resultsHTM = Join-Path $currentDir ("PVSCheckResults.htm")
$errorsHTM = Join-Path $currentDir ("PVSHealthCheckErrors.htm")
```

Here is the error,

```
PS C:\Users\raw.admin> $currentDir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
Split-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null. At line:1 char:26
+ $currentDir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Split-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SplitPathCommand

PS C:\Users\raw.admin>
```

Do I need to create `$currentDir` variable first and set the path?

Answer (score 2):

`$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` isn't populated in the console, because you're not running a script and thus don't have a path to that script.

Comment: Your saying I cant run it in ISE I need to run it with Powershell CMD?

Comment: He is saying that if you wanted to use that it needs to be saved as a script first.

Comment: No worries. Wood. Trees. It happens.